# bash while read loop stops after the first line (after corrections based on a StackExchange post)

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I feel like [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321056/while-read-loop-stops-after-the-first-line-even-though-it-doesnt-read-from-stdi) described exactly my problem, and I made the modifications suggested by Isaac to fix it. That didn't work, so perhaps the problem is something else.

I have written a small script designed to read in IDs from a text file, and perform a database search & fetch using NCBI E-utils (command line version). It successfully fetches and outputs the first fasta sequence, but then exits. I can't figure out why.

```
while IFS='' read -r id || [ "$id" ]
do
    echo "Getting fasta for ${id}"
    esearch -db biosample -query "${id}" --api_key=$mykey | elink -target nuccore | efilter -source refseq | efetch -format fasta > "${id}.fasta"
done < arbank_all_samn_ids.txt
```

I have also tried to add newlines to my file like this:

```
[ -n "$(tail -c1 ids.txt)" ] && printf '\n' >> ids.txt
```

My input file looks like this (about 400 lines):

```
SAMN04014842
SAMN04014843
SAMN04014844
SAMN04014845
```

STDOUT just looks like this right now (plus the single file fetched: SAMN04014842.fasta). Is there something I could add to help troubleshoot?)

```
[me@myserver]$ ./get_seqs.sh
Getting fasta for SAMN04014842
[me@myserver]$
```

Fetching using E-Utils is very finicky anyway, but at this point my problem is that the code exits after one line of the text file. This is the part I'd like to fix (then I'll add some kind of try/except block and a sleep period to manage the constant "500 Internal Server Error").

Many thanks for your help.  I know I must be overlooking something simple, but I haven't found it after an hour of trying different strategies so I appreciate a million more pairs of eyes.

Comment: What is the stdout output? Could you include a fragment of `arbank_all_samn_ids.txt`?

Comment: My apologies - I should have included that info.  I've added it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add logs from running your script with `set -x` logging (as in, `bash -x yourscript`)? Ideally, this'll let you narrow the focus on exactly where something surprising happens, and what that surprising thing is. :)

Comment: BTW, note the quoting bugs in your script (which running it through http://shellcheck.net/ should expose).

Comment: The other thing I don't see you doing here is redirecting stdin from `/dev/null`, as many duplicative questions on the topic teach.

Comment: Missing double quotes around my variable - corrected, thanks!  Redirecting stdin from /dev/null (as also suggested below) seems to have fixed the problem.  Now I'll go read about what that does...haha.  Thank you for your help and corrections!

Comment: Looking at the Perl script that implements `esearch`, I see that it will read from standard input if there are any command line arguments remaining after it processes the options. Using `--api_key` rather than `-api_key` might trigger that.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  esearch was eating up the rest of the file. A user had answered this in a very clear way, but Charles Duffy closed it and marked this a duplicate.  Fair enough, but as a newer programmer those answers are not as clear, particularly as I didn't understand that esearch was causing the error.  Adding </dev/null before the first pipe fixed the problem.  Thanks to the user who added an actual answer because that's what really helped me; otherwise I'd still be scratching my head now.